# Rerun only failed pytests with teamcity

Tags: teamcity, pytest, teamcity-9.1

I'm looking for a way to run only failed pytests during last build.

I've tried --lf option for pytest but it did not help, I guess it is so because of teamcity.

Does anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: You'd probably need to get teamcity to store the `.cache` directory somehow.

Comment: I would check these assumptions: 1st your working directory is not changing during test runs and 2nd your tests are being executed on the same build agent.

Comment: @grundic Yeah, same idea came into my mind, but we are using a small pull of agents. As far as I know Teamcity provides an ability to specify agents for build, not specific run.

Comment: @grundic guess working directory might be a problem, tried on the same agent without success

Comment: @Rabodaber, you should be able to check working directory from the logs of Teamcity, it should be printed somewhere at the beginning of the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to usefull answer, I figured out what was wrong with teamcity.

Multiple builds were using same checkout directory, what caused problems.

As @grundic mentioned:

1. check that your working directory is not changing
2. use same agent